# Internet lags for me, but not for my brother

Tags: windows-7, networking, gaming, latency, priority

Recently we had a **new switch** setup in our basement, plus **my PC has the newest parts** oldest dating 2012. When I play **games that requires instant responding** like Counter-Strike, League of Legends, FIFA on my computer, then when my brother loads a **youtube video, GIF site** or anything else. **My MS screams to 200-500 ms** for a short period or longer depending on video and gif size, but when I load a youtube video or GIF site. His computer feels nothing of it. Only goes from 30 ms which is our connection to a server in london to **70 ms**. We are running LAN to Stationary PCs. We've tried moving the switch plugs around. Tried the router plugs, but to no avail. I'm pretty much at a brick wall of my knowledge where not even my brother can figure it out either. Anyone probably know what my problem is?

Computer

Hardware

- CPU: **Intel i5 3570k 3.4 Ghz**
- Motherboard: **ASUS P8Z77-V LX2**
- RAM: **1x Kingston HyperX 8gb DDR3**

Runs on **Windows 7 Ultimate**

I hope this can help you somewhat with figuring out my issue. I hope you guys can help me with solutions

Comment: Are you both using Win7 Ultimate?

Comment: It just sounds like you two play different games. Latency-sensitive applications and bandwidth-intensive applications just don't play nice together on consumer Internet connections.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some more constellations. What if you and your brother are both watching the *same* video or playing the *same* game? The cause of this may be that the different applications require different QoS. That is, indeed, very useful. Image you download a file, you can wait a bit longer. But if your brother is having a call with a friend on skype and it lags just to complete your download a little bit faster, that would make no sense. That is why different QoS are used. So maybe everything is pretty good the way it is. Or at least as it is intended.

"Fixing" - or better changing - this is eventually difficult. First you should be sure that this is the cause of the issue, so test more as mentioned above. Then maybe install wireshark and check your tcp/ip packets. And if you're sure that is the cause and you're sure you really *want* to change it, you'll have to change the application QoS settings manually. Have a look at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771283.aspx But it can become really nasty.

In my opinion, the best way to solve this problem is to order a better internet connection. if available, of course. otherwise you'll have to ask your brother not to use the connection with a high-priority QoS application when you're playing a game.

Hope this helps you a bit. Generally, there won't be much to fix..

Comment: This is all about QoS, if you're interested have a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service, it explains things rather nicely.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the switch may have Quality Of Service setup to favor his pc over yours.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that his issue is with traffic on his local LAN. It's much more likely that it's his inbound Internet bandwidth that's the issue, and his router's QoS has no control over what packets his ISP sends to him.